# Should questions regarding licenses and usage of OSS from other sites be migrated here

Tags: discussion, migration, site-crossover

I was looking for an answer to a concern of mine and occasionally found it in StackOverflow and it is closed as off-topic which it is there, but I think that the question is pretty on topic in here. Some of the examples below do feel like being a bit off-topic or too broad and might end up closed in here, but SO has a lot questions about licensing (see the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing)) 53 pages as of now, asking about l

> Should we migrate that kind of questions here?

The questions:

- [Does placing GPL licensed software on server qualify as 'distribution' if end user never sees it? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640415/does-placing-gpl-licensed-software-on-server-qualify-as-distribution-if-end-us)
- [GNU gpl licensing for commercial purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123381/gnu-gpl-licensing-for-commercial-purposes)
- [Confused about which software license to use [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096301/confused-about-which-software-license-to-use)

Comment: old questions (+3 month) cannot be migrated whatsoever even by mods.

Comment: This probably should be a separate question, but should we re-post those questions here to preserve the contents and information they contain, or make some wikis

Comment: Meta-Meta question: Are downvotes to questions like this intended to indicate it's a bad question, or that the answer to the question should be no?

Comment: @Martijn [Voting is different on meta](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). For good or for worse, downvoting on questions often indicate “I disagree with what this question proposes” rather than “this question lacks research effort” (this happens even when the question isn't tagged [feature-request], people don't pay close attention to tags when voting).

Comment: This is tagged discussion though, not feature request.

Comment: Usage of OSS? You want this stack to become opensourcesoftwaresupport.SE?

Answer (score 4):

First, during the early beta phase, it's better to avoid migrating questions to the site. The questions may turn out to be unwanted. They may come with answers that this community doesn't like, but migrated threads come with the votes from the original site. There should be no migration until this site has moderators, both because the moderators have the necessary means to counter bad migrations and as a benchmark for when the scope has probably settled down enough.

Furthermore this site needs to be seeded by content that reflects the community that is building it. It is a bad idea to shove in content from elsewhere. We're not trying to carve off a piece of Stack Overflow, we're trying to build a community around open source (or open knowledge or whatever).

In any case [Questions can only be migrated during the first 60 days after posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions/151893#151893). This doesn't make sense but it is clearly not going to change.

If a question has already been asked elsewhere, and it's relevant to this community, then feel free to ask it here, with attribution if necessary, and **in a way that makes sense to *this* community**. If there are interesting answers there, then feel free to post similar material here, with attribution if necessary, but again **in a way that makes sense to *this* community**.

Comment: I agree completely. What would make sense, though, IMHO, is to comment on such thread with a note down the lines of "This question seems like a better fit for the Open Source beta site. Perhaps you should consider asking it there too/instead."

Answer (score 2):

No, there should not be any general migration of questions from anywhere. Ask questions that you genuinely want answered. If we end up with lots of similar questions to Stack Overflow then great. If not, then also great.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

I don't think they should be migrated if

- They would be closed here
- They are closed as a duplicate there
- They are not closed there

Otherwise, I think we should.

Your examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640415/does-placing-gpl-licensed-software-on-server-qualify-as-distribution-if-end-us : Off topic there, on topic here, migrate
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123381/gnu-gpl-licensing-for-commercial-purposes Off topic there, on topic here, migrate
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096301/confused-about-which-software-license-to-use Off topic there, too broad here, don't migrate

Comment: Those ware my thoughts on the 3rd one as well. In fact almost all questions (even those with good quality both Questions and Answers) got closed as the first one did and it really did answered my question, which I was about to post here...

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add something.

Off-topic questions *aren't* bad if they are not blatantly off-topic. These questions help make the definition of the site, helping to explain *exactly* what is on and off-topic. If you would like to see questions here, build upon the closed questions that you see, and make them your own questions. Past-asked migrated questions will not make this beta. Questions by the community will.

If something is on-topic here, then ask it!